# Meteor reactively copy certain fields from user collection to custom userprofiles collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

On Meteor, I have installed `konecty meteor-user-presence` ([link](https://github.com/Konecty/meteor-user-presence)) package to enable user status for each users on my application. This package adds additional fields (status, statusConnection) on Meteor User collection. In my current application setup, I have a different collection called `UserProfiles` that is used to store additional information about each users. I used `id` from the user collection as an identifier for the UserProfiles collection, under the field `owner`.

Is there a way to reactively copy updates from the two fields (status & statusConnection) from the user collection, to the custom UserProfiles collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to achieve this using another package from Atmospherejs called `collection-hooks` {[matb33:collection-hooks](https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks)}. I basically add this into my main.js on the server:

```
Meteor.users.after.update(function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
    UserProfiles.update({
      owner : doc._id
    }, {
      $set: {
        status : doc.status
      }
    }, {multi: true})
});
```

This package add a hook to collections. Every time the application fires update to Meteor.users collection, which is basically every time when the `konecty meteor-user-presence` changes the `status` & `statusConnection` fields in the `user` collection, the `collection-hooks` package hook on the update action and perform additional tasks. The package also has other useful hooks e.g. `before.insert`,`before.update`, `before.remove`,`after.insert`, `after.update` and `after.remove`.

The `{multi: true}` is needed to enable the behaviour to be applied to all users. I do not know whether this will have an impact on the app performance, i'm sure it has some impact especially when the app scales up with large userbase. You should apply this solution carefully.

Here's a good primer for you to start: [A Look At Meteor Collection Hooks](http://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-look-at-meteor-collection-hooks/)